# What is the substance that not all human are able to smell?

Tags: nose, otolaryngology

Some time ago I heard about the existence of a substance that some human are not able to smell. This means if they try to smell it, they don't "feel" any scent... like smelling pure water or pure air.

PS: I heard it during a TV show about flowers but I don't know absolutely if it effectively rely on the flower-world, so I don't know if this information can help

Comment: Interesting question. Though I am not sure to which substance you are referring. Two years ago, there was a very interesting article in Nature Neuroscience called "The missense of smell: functional variability in the human odorant receptor repertoire" by Mainland et al. Without wanting to go into too much details, they showed that there is a huge genetic variation in olfactory perception (they gave the example of more than 30% difference in odorant receptor alleles between 2 persons) between individuals. So probably, there are >1 substance that some individuals can smell and other not. BR

Comment: Here the link to the article: http://www.nature.com/neuro/journal/v17/n1/full/nn.3598.html. Unfortunately it is not open access. I could convert this comment to an answer and give some extracts of the article but maybe someone more updated than me will bring some acurate answer (with a precise name of the substance you are referring to) to your question. Good luck. Best regards. M. Arrowsmith.

Comment: Asparagus gives urine a particular odor. Not all people, however, can smell it.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in a previous answer asparagus has a particular amino acid, asparagine, that not all people can smell.

There are also some medical conditions where particular people can't smell anything. For example, people with Kallmann syndrome often have complete anosmia (inability to smell) because the olfactory receptors do not migrate to the proper location during development.

Comment: Just to clarify: though asparagus contains asparagine, asparagine is made by the body, though probably not in sufficient quantity to be detected by odor in our urine.

Comment: Reference(s) needed please :)